# Create a function to open a new window in tkinter with checkboxes unchecked

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a program to play the game battleship and I designed my gameboard so the user will use a checkbox to select where they want their ships. After "player1" selects their ships I have a "Next" button that will open a new layer for player2 to select their ships, but when it opens the window the boxes that player1 checked in the previous window are already checked. How do I open a new window with blank checkboxes? My code is very long so it is going to be hard to create a small reproducible example but I will do my best. Also, if anyone has any advice on closing windows once a button is clicked I would appreciate it! Right now when I go through it I have 6 windows open at a time which is not very appealing. I've included images of what it looks like after player1's selection and before player2 selects so you can see that the same boxes are checked in player2's window.

Here is a small slice of code from player1:

```
def player():
    player= Toplevel(root)
    placement = Text(player,height=3,width=10)
    placement.insert(END,'Player 1: Place your three ships by selecting three of the blue boxes, then click \'Next\'','place')
    placement.tag_configure('place',font=('times new roman',15))
    placement.config(state=DISABLED)
    placement.config(wrap=WORD)
    placement.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan = 6,rowspan=1, sticky = W+E)
    player.title('Player 1 Ship Placement')
    A = Text(player,height=1,width=10)
    A.insert(END,'A')
    A.config(state=DISABLED)
    A.grid(row=1,column=1)
    A1 = Checkbutton(player,bg='blue')
    A1.config(height=1,width=10)
    A1.grid(row=2,column=1)
    R1 = Text(player,height=1,width=10)
    R1.insert(END,'1')
    R1.config(state=DISABLED)
    R1.grid(row=2,column=0)
    nextb = Button(player,fg='green',text ="Next", command = player2)
    nextb.grid(row=9,column=3)
    nextb.config(height=1,width=10)
```

Here is a small slice of code for player 2:

```
    def player2():
        player2= Toplevel(root)
        placement = Text(player2,height=3,width=10)
        placement.insert(END,'Player 2: Place your three ships by selecting three of the blue boxes, then click \'Next\'','place')
        placement.tag_configure('place',font=('times new roman',15))
        placement.config(state=DISABLED)
        placement.config(wrap=WORD)
        placement.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan = 6,rowspan=1, sticky = W+E)
        player2.title('Player 2 Ship Placement')
        PA = Text(player2,height=1,width=10)
        PA.insert(END,'A')
        PA.config(state=DISABLED)
        PA.grid(row=1,column=1)
        PA1 = Checkbutton(player2,bg='blue')
        PA1.config(height=1,width=10)
        PA1.grid(row=2,column=1)
        PR1 = Text(player2,height=1,width=10)
        PR1.insert(END,'1')
        PR1.config(state=DISABLED)
        PR1.grid(row=2,column=0)
        Pnextb = Button(player2,fg='green',text ="Next", command = player2)
        Pnextb.grid(row=9,column=3)
        Pnextb.config(height=1,width=10)
```

[image: Player 1 Selection]
[image: Player 2 Selection]

Comment: you should use global variable `player` and then you can use `player.destroy()` in function `player2` to close previous window. But you can't use the same name for `def player()` and `player = Toplevel` . It is good rule to use `verb` in function's name - ie. `def run_player()`, `def show_player()`.etc.

Comment: how do you create this checkboxes ? Maybe you use the same variables to keep selections - and then next window use values from other window.

Comment: maybe instead of creating new windows you should create two Frames and replace them in one window - ie. `pack()`, `pack_forget()` - this way you would have to create Frames only once.

Comment: How do I initialize the global variable player? Also I'm assuming this can be done with all the other windows, but can I destroy the root window after we've opened a new one?

Comment: you use `global player` inside function to inform function to use/create global/external variable instead of creating local variable.

Comment: The checkboxes use different variables. The ones for player 1 are A1, A2, A3... and for player2  they are PA1, PA2, PA3...

Comment: do you use `StringVar/BooleanVar` with Checkbutton to remeber its state - `var = BooleanVar()`, `Checkbutton(..., variable=var)` ? Do you use different vars for this ?

Comment: no I don't, let me try that

Comment: when I add var=BooleanVar() and add var to my checkbutton I am no longer able to see the grid. Only the title

Comment: did you run code in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error messages ?

Comment: maybe you will have to show all code to resolve your problem.